# Vectorizing an element-wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, mathematical-optimization

Is it possible to vectorize (or otherwise speedup) an element-wise optimization with NumPy (and SciPy)?

In the most abstract sense, I have a function, y, which is parabolically shaped and could be expressed basically as `y=x^2+b*x+z`, where x is an array of known values, and I want to find a z that makes the minimum value of y exactly zero (said another way, I want to find a value z that makes my parabola only have one zero). For this, I've chosen to implement a simple bisection-like method. The code for this is below:

```
import numpy as np

def find_single_root():
    x = np.arange(-5, 6,0.1) # domain
    z = 1 # initial guess
    delta = 1 # initial step size
    tol = 0.001 # tolerance
    while True:
        y = x**2-5*x+z
        minimum = np.nanmin(y)
        # update z
        print(delta)
        print(z)
        if minimum > 0:
            if delta > 0:
                delta = -1*delta/2
            z += delta
        else:
            if delta < 0:
                delta = -1*delta/2
            z += delta
        # check if step is smaller than tolerance
        if np.abs(delta) < tol:
            return z
```

Now lets say x(v,w), and I want to create a 2D array of z values, where each is optimized. What I have right now is below (note, the new function definition and domain are as follows)

```
def find_single_root(v, w):
    x = np.arange(-5*v/w, 6*w,0.1) # domain
    ... # rest of the function

vs = np.arange(1,5)
ws = np.arange(1,5)
zs = np.zeros((len(vs),len(ws)))
for i, v in enumerate(vs):
    for j, w in enumerate(ws):
        zs[i][j] = find_single_root(v,w)
```

Right now I just have these simple nested for loops, but is there a way I can approach this differently or speed it up with NumPy vectorizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorization may be applicable when the computations to be performed are precisely known in advance. Like "take two arrays of numbers, and multiply them pairwise".

Vectorization is not applicable when the computations *adapt* to the given data. Any kind of optimization algorithm is adaptive, because where you look for the minimum depends on what the function returns. If you have a bunch of functions, and need to find the minimum of each, you are going to have to minimize them one at a time, in a loop. If this process is slow, it's because it takes long to minimize a bunch of function, not because there is a `for` loop in the program.

Concerning your program, I would try using some of SciPy methods for both minimization and root-finding. Have a function `min_of_f(z)` which finds the minimum for a given value of parameter z, possibly using  [`minimize_scalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar).  Then feed `min_of_f` to a [root-finding routine](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/optimize.html#scalar-functions). How long these will take can be controlled by their tolerance parameters (xtol and others).

---

OP edit:
I wanted to give credit for this as a correct answer, but still provide more information.

I ended up using [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to vectorize without restructuring the problem. Although `numpy.vectorize` is not meant for increasing performance, the performance in my specific use case was a modest factor of two faster. Applying the same approach to the original problem in the question resulted in virtually no speed up with 100x100 vectors so YMMV.

Even though I wasn't able to vectorize this problem from a speed aspect for the reasons given in the above answer, being able to use plain vector syntax instead of nested for loops all over my code was useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The numerical complexity of calculating y in my real problem is significant enough so that vectorizing it afforded the entire optimize function a 60x speed up. I see what you mean regarding the adaptive approach, which is why I was asking if there is another (analytical) approach to this problem that would be vectorizable. Ultimately, I could just rewrite this bit in Cython, but that effort wouldn't be worth the performance increase.